# SE friendly URLs apache code snippets

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo

I want **example.com/23-45** be transformed to **example.com?id=23-45**

Could you please post the code I should add to .htaccess file to make this work
(Is this everything I should do to make this work - add a piece of code to .htaccess file?)

Answer (score 0):

You have to have mod_rewrite enabled in Apache's httpd.conf. To use a .htaccess, you also have to have `AllowOverride FileInfo` and `Options FollowSymLinks` for the .htaccess directory in the main configuration. See the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

After that, the .htaccess in the root docs directory should have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^\d+-\d+$ ?id=$0 [B]
```

Comment: I apologise, but have yo tested the second string?

Comment: Your code gave me a 500 error. That's what worked for me
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9\-]+) index.php?id=$0

Answer (score 0):

That's what worked for me

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9\-]+) ?id=$0
```